# I got Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error when trying to import

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am new in vue. i tried to render a vue component. but i got error.
i am not using vue-cli. i include a script https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue

My html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>
            VUE Study
        </title>
        <link href="stylee.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" id="head">
        </div>
        <script src="components/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
import Index from "./Index.vue"

new Vue({
    el: '#head',
    render: h => h(Index)
});
```

both app.js and  Index.vue are in same folder.
Please healp me to solve this..

Comment: Are you using vue-loader and any sort of bundler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because browser do not recognize `import` statement.
Since you are not using a bundler like webpack you can register the components using [Vue.component()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html). This will eliminate the need to import components inside other modules.

```js
Vue.component('Index', {
  data() {
    return {
      value: 'Index component'
    }
  },
  template: `<h2>{{ value }}</h2>`
})

new Vue({
    el: '#head'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>
            VUE Study
        </title>
        <link href="stylee.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" id="head">
            <index />
        </div>
        <script src="components/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```